# Getting Married to a US Citizen, Can I apply for US immigration visa from Sweden where I live on a temporary residence permit

Tags: usa, sweden

I am a Pakistani national master student here in Sweden since 2 years and I will be done with my studies in one more year. I am residing here on a study residence permit from Swedish immigration agency. 
Actually, I am getting married in Jan 2019 (in 3 months from now) and since my  fiancée is a US citizen and living in the US so my question is that after getting married, Am I allowed to file my case for immigration to US here in Sweden or would I have to go back to Pakistan to submit it? If I am allowed, I would like to know some info about the processing time for this visa processing from Sweden.

Looking forward to some thoughtful suggestions/info from you guys.

Thanks for your time already.

Best Regards,

Fahad M :)

Comment: You are allowed to. In actual fact she will file for you and you will do nothing until it is approved and sent to the embassy where you reside. However note the process will take you minimum about a year and a few months. Might be more since you're from Pakistan (and likely a Muslim). That means you will have finished your masters before everything is completed. If you leave Sweden, she/you will have to transfer your case to Pakistan (assuming you return there after you finish) which will add a few more months. Congratulations on getting married!

Comment: This question belongs on [Expatriates.SE].

Comment: @MusoniusRufus Thanks mate, I really appreciate your kind info. I have another question if you could kindly help me with, Actually, I am concerned about the interview and other administrational processing which takes place in this process as suppose If I am residing here in Sweden by that time, is it possible to get it done from US embassy here in Sweden or would I have to go to my country of citizenship for that? I am concerned because I might have to stay here in Sweden for more than one year due to my industrial project.

Comment: @phoog Thanks for suggesting that and I will surly move it into that section :)

Comment: It is not a problem doing it in Sweden because you will be living there legally under a student residence permit. You are not expected to go to Pakistan just for the interview. You can check processing times at https://egov.uscis.gov/processing-times/ and choose form I-130. For the service center you will choose depending on where your fiancee lives.

Comment: @MusoniusRufus Sir Yass Sir :) 
Thank you very much for this valuable info and helping me with this confusion, I really appreciate your help and kind gesture, Have a great day ahead my friend.